# (PERL-> NODEJS) 500: Server closed connection without sending any data back

Tags: node.js, perl, connection-timeout

My Perl script talks to a Node.js server and sends the commands that the Node.js server needs to execute. While some commands take less time, others take a lot longer. While the command is executing on the server, there is silence on the connection. After a while, I receive the `error: 500: Server closed connection without sending any data back`

During this error, the command is still executing on the server and the desired results are obtained (if you check the server logs). My problem is that I don't want the connection to reset as there are other follow on commands that need to run after these long running commands. Some commands might take 20 mins

Perl Side Code:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$ua->timeout(12000);    
my $uri = URI->new('http://server');
my $json = JSON->new;
my $data_to_json = {DATA};
my $json_content = $json->encode($data_to_json);    
# set custom HTTP request header fields
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $uri);
my $resp = $ua->request($req);
my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
```

NodeJS Code

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get('<API URL>', function (req, res) {
    <get all the passed arguments>
    <send output to the console>
});

app.post('<API URL>', function(req, res) {

    .
    .
    .
    req.connection.setTimeout(0);
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var child = exec(command);
    }

// start the server
const server = app.listen(port);
server.timeout = 12000;
console.log('Server started! Listening on port' + port);
```

I have tried to add the timeout for the server using `server.timeout` and `req.connection.setTimeout(0);`.

How do I make sure that the connection is not broken?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4):

It's generally a bad idea to make a web worker carry out long running tasks. It ties up the worker and you end up having problems like this.

Instead, have the web worker add a job to some sort of job queue (Perl's [Minion](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Minion) is really nice). The queue operates independently of the web server. Clients can poll the server to check on the status of a job and get the output or artifacts when it's complete.

Another advantage of a proper job queue is that you can restart jobs if they fail. The queue knows the job was there. As you've seen, a broken web connection means that it fails and you've probably lost track of those inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I will have to move away from the heavy web worker task unless I can figure out something really soon. It seems like a server issue as I have even put `my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 1)` but for no avail

Comment: I changed the timeout to 0 and it seems to work. But in longer term, I am working to move away from long times for opening up the connection. `server.timeout = 0;`